# Bind property to method

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am developing a Windows 8 App in C# and using databinding

```
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Name="departments"
    Source="{Binding Departments}"
    d:Source="{Binding AllGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:Department, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

I can bind the properties of this class to my UI, but the class also has this method I need

```
public String getProfessorsList()
```

I would like to be able to bind the method like this...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding getHeads()}" FontSize="18" />
```

...but obviously this is not allowed. How can I acheve this functionality?

Comment: Bind to an auto-implemented property whose getter returns the method call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just adding a getter-property that returns that method:

```
public string ProfessorsList { get { return this.getProfessorsList(); } }
```

And then bind to that property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding professorsList}" FontSize="18" />
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that if the string returned by ProfessorsList changes, your UI won't change to reflect that. And if that's acceptable, then for performance reasons, you should set the binding Mode to OneTime.

Comment: You can get around the issue mentioned by @KshitijMehta if you know when the string changes.  In that case you can still call the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` method for the `ProfessorsList` property and it will update appropriately.

Comment: How would you go about passing a parameter to the Method?