# Bind DataGridTextColumn to method WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to bind a DataGridTextColumn to a method in my xaml.cs?

This is my XAML

```
           <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IdItem}" Header="Id Item" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True"/>

                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding concatenarMoneda}" Header="Costo" Width="*"/>
            </my:DataGrid.Columns>
```

and I want to bind the second column to the following function

```
private string concatenarMoneda
    {
        get { 
            return viewModel.Registro.Costo.ToString() + " " + viewModel.Registro.SOSMoneda.Descripcion; 
        }
    }
```

This should result in two properties being concatenated in the same column

I have seen this working with a textblock but it is not working in this case.

See [Bind property to method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467043/bind-property-to-method)

**UPDATE** more code as requested

this is my whole grid

```
  <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="{DynamicResource GrisOscuro}">
        <my:DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="False" x:Name="DataGridDatos" Margin="32"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="White"                    
                     SelectionChanged="DataGridDatos_SelectionChanged"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding Registro}"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Registros}"
                     IsEnabled="{Binding DataGridDatosEstado}"
                     SelectedIndex="{Binding IndiceActual}"
                     IsReadOnly="True">
            <my:DataGrid.Columns>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IdItem}" Header="Id Item" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SOSProveedor.Nombre}" Header="Proveedor" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SOSServicio.Descripcion}" Header="Servicio" Width="*"/>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SOSUbicacion.Descripcion}" Header="Ubicacion" Width="*"/>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SOSTipoPagoItem.Descripcion}" Header="Tipo Pago Item" Width="*"/>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FechaInicioVigencia , StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yy}}" Header="Fecha Inicio" Width="*"/>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Estatus}" Header="Estatus" Width="*"/>
                <my:DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
            Path=concatenarMoneda,Mode=OneWay}" Header="Costo" Width="*"/>
            </my:DataGrid.Columns>
        </my:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

that grid is sorrounded by  which is the parent element within the XAML

on the other in my xaml.cs I've got the **concatenarMoneda** function that I showed above

and my ViewModel brings all the data from the Model... using methods such as this

```
public ObservableCollection<SOSItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (_items == null)
            {
                _items = new ObservableCollection<SOSItem>(db.SOSItems.Select(AppRow => AppRow));
            }
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
```

Maybe the ancestor type you suggest should be other than

```
  AncestorType={x:Type Window}
```

?

Comment: Might work when you use  multibinding and a multiValueConverter

Comment: here you can find an example of this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-multi-binding-and-multi-value-conv

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you. Seems like too much code for such a little thing !! but ok

Comment: I don't really know how to use that converter within my dataGridTextColumn... I've already created the converter but can not find a way to use it.  dataGridTextColumn does not accept multibinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use IMultiValueConverter as GertHermans mentioned.

```
 <DataGridTextColumn  Width="70" Header="Costo">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConcatConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Costo" />
                        <Binding Path="SOSMoneda.Descripcion" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>



 public class ConcatConverter : IMultiValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                return values[0].ToString() + " " + values[1].ToString();
            }



            public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I just tried that but it is not working.. maybe something is lacking?

Comment: Can you post more code to understand your issue better

Comment: I just posted some more code which I believe is relevant to the problem

Comment: As Gert Hermans mentioned you need to use IMultiValueConverter.